# How can I return the design of each text I have in the PHPWORD library?

Tags: php, docx, doc, phpword

After a lot of research, I just found a way to read the doc and docs files. But I don't know how to return the design of its texts and put it in a table.

**Here is the code I had used to return the content of the doc file.**

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory as WordIOFactory;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$source = 'test/example.doc';
$objReader = WordIOFactory::createReader('MsDoc');
$phpWord = $objReader->load($source); // instance of \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord
$text = '';

function getWordText($element) {
    $result = '';
    if ($element instanceof AbstractContainer) {
        foreach ($element->getElements() as $element) {
            $result .= getWordText($element);
        }
    } elseif ($element instanceof Text) {
        $result .= $element->getText();
    }
    // and so on for other element types (see src/PhpWord/Element)

    return $result;
}

foreach ($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
    foreach ($section->getElements() as $element) {
        $text .= getWordText($element);
    }
}

echo $text;
```

**Can you help me to return the design of each text I have, one by one, and put it into an array?**

I would like to return them so I can create a new doc file with my text and design.

Comment: _"return the design of each text"_ I don't understand what this means. Please describe what you're getting and what you want to get.

Comment: @alex-howansky I don't just want to get the text. I want to contain it. It's the image, their whole design. Then I just want to replace the text with another text. In fact, I want to replace the text in my file with another one without losing any data.

Comment: @Richard Please explain what do you mean by "design" of a text. Is it font size, colors, etc.?